# Authentication Options with Expo RN app using Firebase backend

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, expo

I am evaluating some authentication options for a React Native App using Expo and Firebase as my backend. 
My goal is to keep the code similar between Expo Client Managed workflow and Expo standalone app (not ejected).

I would like to have Apple, Google and Facebook sign in options in the app.

I am leaning towards the following  Auth mechanism and would like to get some feedback from the community.

**For Google Sign in**

1. Use Expo [AppAuth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/app-auth/) to sign in the user first.
2. Then having received auth credentials from Google use Firebase [signInWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithcredential)

Note for Google Sign in I am not using [Google](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) sign or [GoogleSignIn](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/) because they differ between Expo client builds (development time) and Expo standalone (production)

**For Apple Authentication**

Very similar to the above -

1. Use [AppleAuthentication](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/apple-authentication/) to sign in the user.
2. Having received auth credentials from Apple use Firebase [signInWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithcredential)

**For Facebook Sign in**

1. Use Expo [AppAuth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/app-auth/) to sign in the user first, using (facebook.com OAuth provider)
2. Then having received auth credentials from Facebook use Firebase [signInWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithcredential)

With this approach I may be able to keep the same code path for dev and prod (only changing the package name or bundle id).

Is this the right approach for Auth?

Comment: If you're looking for general opinions or suggestions, it's better to post to a discussion group. Questions seeking opinions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I posted here because this straddles more than one product / APIs and this is guidance for a specific solution in this case, perhaps my post was not worded like that - thanks!